# Axios in nodejs returns error 'too many results'

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

From my Nodejs application I'm trying to ask an external API for some data. The request looks like this:

```
axios.post('apiUrl', {
    fromDate: '2020-02-20',
    toDate: '2020-06-03',
}
```

However, I get this as a result:

```
    data: {
        success: false,
        content: null,
        displayErrorMessage: 'Too many results.',
        serverErrorMessage: ''
  }
```

Running the request on Postman with the exact same data, or even a longer timestamp, works 100% fine and I get the expected response.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Try to limit your needed results.

Comment: I can't, I'm rebuilding an old application and the timestamp I ask for is what's required.

Comment: Can you generate a `curl` from your postman request and add it to the question?